# Is it possible to test whether a C define is declared in a gnu Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I want to include different directories in my build based on whether a #define is declared in a .h file in my project.  Is this possible or am I going about this completely wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are. The build system is supposed to configure the code, not vice-versa. You should use a configure script for this kind of options (or probably switch to a higher build system: autotools, CMake, QMake...).

Answer (score 4):

The other answers have explained why this is a bad idea. Nonetheless, one way to do it is by preprocessing a makefile fragment:

In `foo.mk.in`:

```
#ifdef FOO
FOO_DEFINED := y
#else
FOO_DEFINED := n
#endif
```

In `Makefile`:

```
foo.mk: foo.mk.in
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
include foo.mk
ifeq ($(FOO_DEFINED),y)
$(warning FOO is defined)
else
$(warning FOO is not defined)
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you are going about this the wrong way. The way to include different directories is with different make targets. If your code has to know about them, use `-D` in your compiler switches. Alternatively, if your build needs to be able to run on other people's systems, something like [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) is the way to go.